# bug tracking on a per project basis

Tags: bug-tracking, bugzilla, mantis

been looking into bug tracking solutions. searched the net, other sites, as well as other replies/questions here,

i've got a project that will have multiple subprojects. each subproject will have a need to have its' own bug tracking space. ie, projectA, projectB, and projectC will be worked on by different people, and will generate different issues/bugs that need to be resolved/tracked by the devs.

in taking a quick look at the free tools, (bugzilla/mantis/etc..) not sure if there's a quick/easy approach to creating a solution for my needs.

i'm looking at having ~200-300 subprojects, each with 1-2 devs..

can't go fee based, as this is a small/not funded operation, and the project will have more than the number of devs/subprojects specified by the free operations from the fee based apps.

thoughts/comments are appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly this situation at work, and after evaluating all the options, decided to go with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). Redmine has the concept of multiple projects, each with their own bug and feature tracker, wiki space, version control integration, document storage, news feed, etc. The projects can be hierarchically nested as well, which is a really nice feature. You can also set up project roadmaps and link features to specific releases.

You can set up custom roles, and developers can have different project management rights for each project they are a member of.

My favourite feature is the source code management integration. It's great to be able to link bugs to individual SVN commits, and clicking through to see the diff is really helpful.

The code is implemented using Ruby on Rails, with a DB backend (we use MySQL). It is our production bug tracker, and has been very reliable. The project itself uses Redmine for it's own [bug tracking](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues). It is well supported, open source, and there has been steady progress and improvements in the 2 years we have been using it.

There's an [interactive demo site](http://demo.redmine.org/) that you can have a look at, if you want to get a feel for Redmine's capabilities before you download it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla has a "strict isolation" mode that makes it anal about group security.  Each subproject could have its own group that's distinct to those devs.

Alternatively, you could use the same installation but with multiple databases:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/multiple-bz-dbs.html

Redmine (or similar) might be a better alternative for what you want, but that's how'd you do it in Bugzilla.